# Sending attachment in laravel mail

Tags: email, laravel-5.4, email-attachments

everyone. I am trying to send email with attachment on it. What I have done is :

```
   controller code snippet:

     try{
           Mail::send(['name' => 'By System'],array(), function($msg) use ($email,$name,$message,$attachment,$ext,$display) {
                        $msg->from('ricket999@gmail.com', 'Markle Admin');
                        $msg->to($email)->subject('Payment Done')
                            ->setBody('This is to notify you that the employee named '.$name.' has been paid for the monthly payment. Thank You.','text/html')
                            ->attach(public_path().'/'.$attachment, ['as' => $display.'.'.$ext, 'mime' => 'application/pdf']);  });
        }
    catch(Exception $e){
             // if any error mark the mail sent status 0
             $result = DB::table('message')->where('name',$name)->where('email',$email)->update(['sent'=>'0']); 
            }
```

But it is showing this error :

```
    Type error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, string given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\email-send\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php on line 133
```

What have I missed. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917977/laravel-mailsend-with-multiple-attachment) and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail) but it is same as mine and they say its working but why am I getting this error. Any kind of help are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have tagged it as laravel-5.4 and you are referring to documentation of laravel-5.1. 
Apart form that it seems to me that either file is corrupted or path is not correct.

Comment: @ChrysovalantisKoutsoumpos okay I have corrected the link and this is what is being passed to mail  :   Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage->attach('E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email-send\\public/files/1520764563.zip', array('as' => 'somename.zip', 'mime' => 'application/pdf')). I think the path and files are correct as it is opened with the above file path when opened from run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. You are trying to attach a zip archive while you have set the mime as `application/pdf`
2. The path to your archive is wrong.
   Instead of 
   `E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email-send\\public\\files\\1520764563.zip` it is `E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email-send\\public/files/1520764563.zip`

Regarding the `Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, string given` error I suppose that this solves your problem:

```
    $swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($correctPath); 
    $this->email->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type
```

Comment: Okay here I tried your suggestion 
at Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage->attach('E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email-send\\public\\files\\1520768296.pdf', array('as' => 'somename.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf')). But still same error.

Comment: it is saying " Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, string given ". It is taking filepath as string.