# Send attached file email with Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to send an attached file with the Laravel function Mail, but it is not working, it shows the next error:

Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, string given, called in /home/jysparki/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/BillController.php on line 640 and defined

My code is this one:

```
  $email = Email::find(22);

    $body = $email->email;

    $client = Our_Client::find($invoice_history->id_client);

    $search  = array('$client_name', '$folio', '$amount', '$bill_date');
    $replace = array($client->client, $invoice_history->folio, $invoice_history->amount, Helper::fixdate($invoice_history->bill_date));

    $body = str_replace($search, $replace, $body);


    $search  = array('$folio');
    $replace = array($invoice_history->folio);

    $subject = $email->subject;

    $subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

    $data = array( 'email' => 'rodrigocabezas@jisparking.cl', 'subject' => $subject, 'body' => $body , 'file' => $file_url);

    Mail::send([], $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
      $message->to($data['email'])
        ->subject($data['subject'])
        ->setBody($data['body'], 'text/html') // for HTML rich messages
        ->attach($data['file'], ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf']);
    });
```

How you can see i am passing the file here:

```
  ->attach($data['file'], ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf']);
```

This $data['file'] contains the url to the file, I tested it and it is ok it shows me thye file in thye browser.

What can the problem be?

Thanks

Comment: You are passing wrong data type in attach method. Have you tried `attachFromStorage` or `Swift_Attachment::fromPath` instead?

Comment: Possibly related to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219301/sending-attachment-in-laravel-mail